# Hibernate using sql call for each row to fetch relationship - instead of aggregating to one IN clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `User` object with an `addresses` `set` to `Address`. Now let's say I need to fetch 1,000,000 users and display their address in some report.

The `Hibernate` way to do it is to create one `sql` call to the `User` table, and then another call to the `Address` table for each user. The result is a grand total of 1,000,001 calls and a long query time.

On the other hand if you aggregate all the foreign keys (for example `User_Id`) and run an `IN` sql call

```
FROM Address where User_Id IN (,,,,,,,,)
```

you reduce the number of calls to 2 - one to the User table and one to the Address table, to bring all the 1,000,000 required address in one call.

But this requires some work on the app side. Not a lot of work, just a `for loop`, but still. Is it possible to ask Hibernate to do it the efficient way?

Please note that `LAZY fetching` has nothing to do with it. For my use case I need an `EAGER fetching`.

Comment: Andy why dont you simply eager fetch required `address` field ?

Comment: @Antoniossss because that's exactly the problem. Hibernate would do 1,000,001 queries in this case. Set `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` and see for yourself.

Comment: Hibernate will generatesingle query using `JOINS`. I dont know what sort of configuration you are using whatsoever.`SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.address` would give u `address` via joins. Single query

Comment: Yes, that's great. It should be an answer to this question and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: your wish is granted:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate will generate single query using `JOINS`. I dont know what sort of configuration you are using whatsoever.`SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.address` would give u address via joins. Single query

Comment: Actually it's a single query if you don't use a hibernate relationship between user and address. But when you do, an Eager fetch would do an extra querie, and if you use a Lazy fetch you'd have to use the extra query later when retrieving the address.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make 2 queries. I use Java 8 stream.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User").setMaxResult(BATCH);
List<User> users = query.list();
final List<Integer> userIds = users.stream()
                                          .map(u -> u.getUserId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
query = session.createQuery("FROM Address where User_Id IN (:ids)").setListParametrs(userIds);
final List<Address> result = query.list();
```

Also I would like to suggest do not get 1,000,000 rows in 1 query, use batch processing.

Comment: Yes, these are the 2 queries I was talking about. But you still have to collect the userId's and then match each address to its user. Again, not a lot of work but still. (Thanks for the cool new way for collecting the user ids without a for loop.)

Comment: And no, I'm not fetching a million object in one batch. This is just an example.